# VTK import error when trying to using PyMAPDL

Tags: pyvista

While replicating solved Example from PyMAPDL https://mapdl.docs.pyansys.com/version/stable/examples/gallery_examples/00-mapdl-examples/exhaust_manifold_thermal_stress.html

I m finding the error with VTK and following is the error

ImportError: cannot import name 'VTK9' from 'pyvista._vtk' (c:\Users\yashp\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\pyvista_vtk.py)

I have try to use lower version of pyvista but that also doesnt work for me.
Let me know What is wrong and how can I fix this?

Answer (score 1):

This answer should be a comment but it's too long to fit into one.

> I have try to use lower version of pyvista but that also doesnt work for me.

You should be more specific about the version you have and the lower version that "didn't work".

PyVista increased its lowest supported VTK version to 9.0 [in this PR](https://github.com/pyvista/pyvista/pull/4018), which was released with [PyVista 0.39.0](https://github.com/pyvista/pyvista/releases/tag/v0.39.0) two weeks ago. This is when `pyvista._vtk.VTK9` was removed.

So if you downgrade PyVista to 0.38.6 or older you *should* have `pyvista._vtk.VTK9`. Please check again what versions you tried, and whether you downgraded PyVista in the right environment.

Furthermore, the path you have in your question:

> c:\Users\yashp\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\pyvista_vtk.py

doesn't look quite right. It looks as if it were referring to a module called `pyvista_vtk.py`, which looks wrong to begin with, and it's even more wrong if we consider that `.py` files are few and far between in `site-packages\` folders, and anything `pyvista` should be located in a directory called `pyvista` as far as I know, so the path should end with `site-packages\pyvista\_vtk.py`.

So if properly downgrading PyVista in the correct env doesn't work, please explain in your question how your env was created, what tool (venv, conda etc.) you used to create it, and what `pyvista.Report()` tells you.

Answer (score 1):

The solution to your problem is to downgrade `pyvista` to 0.37.0.

Check the solution given in here: https://github.com/ansys/pymapdl/issues/2058

If downgrading `pyvista` is not an option (as you seems to mention), you can install `pymapdl` directly from the main branch (cloning the repo and installing it using `pip install .`) since that version works.